# How to write if and join statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i perform both if and join statement in sql like:

```
if (t1.street != ' ' and t2.street != ' ')
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.street = t2.street.
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/554639)

what i want is to join only if both street != ' '

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com demo with sample data and show desired result.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de1be/2/0

```
select * from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.street = t2.street AND (t1.street != ' ' and t2.street != ' ')
```

Add the condition to the join

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a where condition.

```
SELECT      *
FROM        table1 t1 
INNER JOIN  table2 t2 on t1.street = t2.street
WHERE       t1.Street != ''
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ce8f/3

Don't need to check if t2.Street is != '' because t1.Street == t2.Street